# Magento rewrite tags url

Tags: url, url-rewrite, tags

I had created tag called test in Magento but its default url is like `tag/product/list/tagId/1/` but i need the url  to be like the `tag/test`.

I tried [magento-tag-url-rewrite-and-generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320857/magento-tag-url-rewrite-and-generate) and [magento-tag-url-rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414177/magento-tag-url-rewrite), but it returns `404 page not found` on accessing the url like tag/test.

Please Help Me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24608684/2047249.
You can find the code provided in the answer as an extension here: https://github.com/tzyganu/EasylifeTag.

The main idea is to create a custom router that handles the urls like `tag/something` and to rewrite the tag model so the urls generated will be `tag/something` instead of `tag/product/list/tagId/1/`

Answer (score 0):

Tag is the module name while `product` or `test` (in your case) are the controller name. You can't get the `tag/test/..` url unless you have `testController.php` in  Tag module's controller folder. As this is custom url so the simple way is to create this file and place in `app/code/local/Mage/Tag/controllers/` and then code in that file according to your requirements.