# Magento 1.9 : TAGs implementation

Tags: magento-1.9, tags

I want to add tags to my products and my question is how do you organize this. What I know for now thinks to do.

1. I must change tags page url to look nicer

> NO: ../tag/product/list/tagId/1/
>
> YES: ../tag/My-Tag

I have found the nice post about that (not tested yet)
link: [Magento rewrite tags url](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29187/magento-rewrite-tags-url)

2. I think the good idea would be to add some description about 300 words to every tag- I guess this would bust SEO - not really sure how to solve that.
3. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -2):

If by tag pages, you mean duplicate or think content pages with a list of keywords, this is NOT good for SEO

I would recommend not having these pages, serving 404 or add a meta noindex

Otherwise if these are main content pages, then are they already ranking?

If so, changing their URL will BREAK that ranking.

If not, then choose a URL structure that contains the 1 main keywords you want to rank for, preferably in the page name

and Make sure the total URL string is less than 90 characters!